# Angular ng-model Input from rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just ran into a simple problem with angular. 
I have an Input field with a placeholder "Username".
If a User is selected and thus available in the $rootScope, the ng-model is displayed.

This works so far...

```
 input type="text" placeholder="Username..." ng-model="user.name + user.id"/>
```

**Current Output in the View:**

```
Username12
```

**What I want to be the Output is:**

```
Username (12)
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you probably would like to do something with the value of the `<input>` element (otherwise use a different read only approach), `ng-model` should stand for a simple variable name (no calculation / concatenation).

To do so, you should use `$watch('user', ...` to generate the updated `<input>` value each time `user` object change .

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username..." ng-model="userInput" />
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: "Marc",
    id: 1
  };
  
  $scope.userInput = '';
  
  // ...
        
  $scope.$watch('user', function(user){
    $scope.userInput = user.name + ' (' + user.id + ')';
  });
  
});
```

---

### Online Demo

#### https://plnkr.co/edit/DqjFIiiU8EJmHWUhJdGl?p=preview

Comment: Thanks you! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model if you want a databinding.

It looks here that you just want to print (and not update) these values.

Then I would suggest of just using a simple html tag with a print instead of wrapping the data (in a wrong way) in an input.

You could for instance do something like a normal binding on any html-element:

```
<span ng-bind="user.name"></span>(<span ng-bind="user.id"></span>)
```